# How does substituting yogurt into a cake change the texture and why can it be used?

Tags: substitutions, cake, yogurt

I've read about using yogurt in cake recipes to make them healthier. I was wondering how and why does replacing the fat by yogurt work, in particular whether the cake becomes rubbery and how to avoid this.

Comment: substituting yogurt in place of what?

Comment: Instead of the oil, I can't see how it would work and am interested in the science behind it

Answer (score 2):

I am always reminded of a quotation from one of the early episodes of "Two Fat Ladies" the BBC cooking show that yogurt is NOT a substitute for cream. I found that if I needed to address the dietary concerns of a guest, I found it easier to cook recipes that called for yogurt as a base rather than experimenting with an existing recipe that required cream or cheese.

The recipes often depend of the fat content of cream or creamed cheese to provide moisture to your baking etc.

If we are talking about baked deserts, there are a wonderful range of Indian desserts that start with a yogurt dairy base instead of needing cream and milk.

I find that a useful dessert is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrikhand